# Multiple domains and SSL : all domains use my SSL certificate but I don't want?

Tags: apache, ssl

I have a wildcard SSL certificate on my apache server. It works perfectly with my domain, but the mistake is that it works with all the domains on my apache server ! And I don't want it, when I go on https://www.mywebsitewithouthttps.com, firefox tell me that the page is not secure because the certificate is for www.mydomainwithhttps.com. If I add an exception for this SSL error on my browser, it is not "mywebsitewithouthttps.com" that is display but "mydomainwithhttps.com" (on this URL : https://www.mywebsitewithouthttps.com) !

I don't want my certificate to work for all the other domains ! It's a big problem because Google is crawling and indexing all my other domains on HTTPS with the content of mydomainwithhttps.com :-(

This my virtualhost for SSL :

```
NameVirtualHost *:443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.mydomainwithhttps.com    
    DocumentRoot "/home/mydomainwithhttps/www"

    suPHP_Engine On
    suPHP_AddHandler x-httpd-php
    suPHP_UserGroup mydomainwithhttps users
    AddHandler x-httpd-php .php

    SSLEngine on 
    SSLCertificateFile /certificates/ssl_certificate.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /certificates/www.mydomainwithhttps.com.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /certificates/IntermediateCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You have a wildcard SSL ***certificate***. SSL Is a secure transport. Off topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you make a HTTPS request the client will establish a TCP connection to the relevant IP and port (usually 443) at the server. If the connection succeeded it will start the TLS handshake and during the TLS handshake it will get the certificate for validation.

If you have **multiple servers at the same IP address and port** they all share the same TCP listener. Since the TCP connection attempt has no information about the targets server name but only has the targets IP address and port the listener will accept all connection attempts, even if the (yet unknown) target hostname has no HTTPS configured.

Modern clients then send the target hostname inside the TLS handshake and only then the server knows what the client wants. If it has HTTPS configured for the requested name the server can send the appropriate certificate. If HTTPS is not configured  for this name the server will either send a default certificate or close the connection (maybe send a TLS alert when closing).

In summary this leaves you with the following options:

1. Use a different IP address for HTTPS sites and non-HTTPS sites. This way the TCP connection will already fail because the server is not listening for connections on this IP:port.
2. Configure your server to return an error when the client requests a hostname for which no HTTPS is configured. This way the client will probably get some strange error message about HTTPS problem in the browser. I'm not sure but maybe you can setup Apache this way when using the `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on` option. If this option does not help then apache might not support this kind of setup.
3. Configure your server to use a default certificate (usually the first configured certificate) whenever the name does not match or the client does not support SNI. The client will get a certificate mismatch warning in the browser.  This is the setup you currently have.
4. Setup HTTPS properly for **all** domains either by having separate certificates or by including them all into a single certificate.

Thus to make sure that the bots don't assume that your site can do HTTPS you need to go with option 1 or 2. Please note also that in all of these cases you expect the bots to support SNI, which not all do. Therefore for best compatibility you would need to use a separate IP address for each HTTPS site.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the multi domain with SSL and with different certificate on both UBUNTU and RHEL by following [multi donain with ssl](https://kalaivairamuthu.wordpress.com/2019/06/13/ssl-configuation-for-multiple-domain/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Apache will try to find config for https://www.mywebsitewithouthttps.com/ and when it doesn't, it will default back to the first https config (the one for mydomainwithhttps).

This will show a cert error but, as you've experienced, if you click through, you see the wrong site.

I cannot however understand Google crawling and indexing the site. I would have thought it would have stopped when it saw the cert error? I'd be very surprised if that is not the case but if it's not you can put a rewrite rule on for those hostname a to redirect back to http.

There's only 2 ways around this:

1. Get certs for the other domains so you can connect via https. You can still redirect back to http if you really want.
2. Separate out the servers with https to a different server (or a different IP on the same server and set up Apache config to listen on port 443 on https IP address only).

That's just the way Apache (and most - if not all - other webservers) work.